# Ordering by specific id and not by total of column

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have this query in a PHP file:

```
SELECT COUNT(pilotid) as total, depicao FROM db_pireps
GROUP BY depicao ORDER BY total DESC
LIMIT 5
```

In my HTML, I then get the results from the database and use `foreach($fav_deps as $departure)`

```
$fav_deps = DB::get_results($dep_query);
```

Inside the foreach, a row generates for each record. One column should calculate the amount of times the pilot has departed from a specified airport. However, `$departure->total` assumes the actual total departures from the airport, and I'd like to make it so it calculates the total departures for a `pilotid` from a specified airport, which in this case is `depicao`. How can I achieve this?

```
<td width="20%"><?php echo $departure->total; ?></td>
```

Additionally, I have attached a screenshot to illustrate how db_pireps is structured.

[image: table]

Comment: Could you give an example of the result you would like (ie which columns)?

Comment: There are 4 columns. ICAO code of the airport, country name, airport name and the total count of departures. i.e `EGGP Liverpool Airport United Kingdom 14`. But number `14` is the amount of total departures by everyone, and I'd like it specific for a `pilotid`.

Comment: So you'd want pilotid as a column too?

Comment: No, I want the total count of departures from an airport, but assigned to `pilotid`. So example let's say that picture is the full table, `pilotid` 2 had 1 departure from `EGKK`, and so on.

Comment: You could have a key called "pilot_total_departures" into the pilot's array. So, inside the foreach loop, you would only need to check if the key is present (and increasing it to represent "another departure for that pilot") ot not (adding the key to the array, pre-set to 1).

Comment: `$userinfo->pilotid` should limit it to a given pilot. How can I combine it with `$departure->total`. So total departures for pilotid, in theory it would work, I guess?

Answer (score 0):

You should group by pilotid too, and select that column, this way you get the result you wanted.

```
SELECT COUNT(pilotid) as total, depicao, pilotid FROM db_pireps GROUP
BY depicao, pilotid ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 5
```

If you go through the result of this, `$departure->total` will contain the value only for a given pilot.

Comment: That's working, but now I get duplicate records, I assume this is because it counts other pilots too? It should only account for a single pilot, much like displaying statistics on pilot's profile.

Comment: However, `$userinfo->pilotid` should limit it to a given pilot. How can I combine it with `$departure->total`?