# Linking two PHP objects together

Tags: php

I have these two objects:

```
$userinfo->pilotid;
$departures->total;
```

I'm trying to get `$departures->total` for specific `pilotid` in `$userinfo` = `$userinfo->pilotid`.

However, I'm not sure how can I link them so it echoes A for B. I have something like this but it does not display anything.

```
<?php echo $pilotid->$departures->total; ?>
```

Additionally, the first object is called like this:

```
$pilotid = Auth::$userinfo->pilotid;
```

This is the structure of the table where the objects are gathered from, using a query.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaYVe.jpg]

Comment: Now, since the formalities are out of the way, let's see if I can help you. What is the exact structure of `$userinfo`?

Comment: So what's in `$userinfo->pilotid` and in `$departures->total`? Arrays, strings, scalars?

Comment: Try putting the output of `var_dump` here please.

Comment: I don't see why `$userinfo->pilotid` can't be an array?!

Comment: @Havelock You're right, it could be an array. However `$userinfo` is clearly an object, as is `$depatures`, and the way I understand the question, the poster wishes to link them together somehow.

Comment: Yes, the OP originally said `I have these two arrays $userinfo->pilotid and $departures->total`, where you said they're not arrays, can't see why.

Comment: `$departures` might be entirely different from `$userinfo` - probably with its own business logic. Without more information, there's not much we can do

Comment: @zzwyb89, what are the contents of the two properties `$userinfo->pilotid` and `$departures->total`?

Comment: They're both integers. As in the table above, that I have just posted, pilotid is a number, as is the `$departures->total` not visible on the table, but it calculates total number of departures for `pilotid`

Comment: This is very much related to your original question; you should edit your question to mention it:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15052778/ordering-by-specific-id-and-not-by-total-of-column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stemming from the data provided by the OP, I am assuming, that `$departures` has a 1:n relationship with `$userinfo`, `$userinfo` being the 1 containing the pilotid.

So, in oder to find out how many departures that pilot had in total, there's two possible ways, one by using a subquery, which would mean something like this:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `departures` WHERE `pilot_id` = ID) as total, * FROM pilots;
```

In this case, your total would be in the `total` column of your `$userinfo` query.

The second attempt makes use of actual PHP. In this scenario, you do the counting yourself.

First step: Getting the pilot information:

```
$userinfo = array();
while($row = fetch()) {
    $row->total = 0;
    $row->departures = array();
    $userinfo[$row->pilotid] = $row;
}
```

These lines will give you the pilot data keyed to their IDs in an array.
Step two. Glueing the departures to the pilots.

```
while($row = fetch()) {
    if(isset($userinfo[$row->pilotid])) {
        $userinfo[$row->pilotid]->departures[] = $row;
        ++$userinfo[$row->pilotid]->total;
    }
}
```

If this isn't what you're looking for, I will be needing more information from you, however like this you will be able to get the departures of the pilots either by making use of the `total` variable in the `$userinfo` object, or by simply calling `count` on the `departures` array.

Another variant, which keeps the actual departures and the pilots apart would look like this:

First step: Getting the pilot information:

```
$userinfo = array();
while($row = fetch()) {
    $row->total = 0;
    $userinfo[$row->pilotid] = $row;
}
```

These lines will give you the pilot data keyed to their IDs in an array.
Step two. Glueing the departures to the pilots.

```
$departures = array();
while($row = fetch()) {
    if(isset($userinfo[$row->pilotid])) {
        $departures[] = $row;
        ++$userinfo[$row->pilotid]->total;
    }
}
```

I hope you will find these suggestions useful.

Edit:
After a few additional information from the OP, I suggest changing the query used to access the information in question.

This is the original code by the OP

```
$dep_query = "SELECT COUNT(pilotid) as total, depicao, pilotid FROM phpvms_pireps GROUP
    BY depicao, pilotid ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 5";

    $fav_deps = DB::get_results($dep_query);

    foreach($fav_deps as $departure)
    {
            $dep_airport = OperationsData::getAirportinfo($departure->depicao);
            $pilotid = Auth::$userinfo->pilotid;
    ?>
            <tr class="awards_table1">
                    <td width="10%"><?php echo $departure->depicao; ?></td>
                    <td width="10%"><img src="<?php echo Countries::getCountryImage($dep_airport->country); ?>" /></td>
                    <td width="60%"><?php echo $dep_airport->name; ?></td>
                    <td width="20%"><?php echo $pilotid->{$departures->total}; ?></td>
            </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

First thing we'll change is the query used to get the departures. Why fetch all the information, if we actually only want the one of the pilot in question?

```
$pilotid = $userinfo->pilotid; //As per Chat discussion
$dep_query = "SELECT COUNT(depicao) as total, depicao FROM phpvms_pireps WHERE pilotid = $pilotid GROUP BY depicao ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 5";
```

This query will return the Top 5 of the departures from the different airports, which have been run by the pilot in question. As for the rest:

```
$fav_deps = DB::get_results($dep_query);

if(is_array($fav_deps)) {    //For the general use
    foreach($fav_deps as $departure) {
        $dep_airport = OperationsData::getAirportinfo($departure->depicao); ?>
        <tr class="awards_table1">
            <td width="10%"><?php echo $departure->depicao; ?></td>
            <td width="10%"><img src="<?php echo Countries::getCountryImage($dep_airport->country); ?>" /></td>
            <td width="60%"><?php echo $dep_airport->name; ?></td>
            <td width="20%"><?php echo $departure->total; ?></td> //Here is the actually changed Layout code
        </tr>
<?php 
    } 
} else echo "This pilot didn't have any departures yet.";
```

?>

With these alterations, your code should output the desired result. It is completely untested though. However it should give you the right idea.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. To fill you in a bit more, `$userinfo` is already setup in the structure of my CMS. Here's my full code: http://pastebin.com/eiQAwxEg. Let me give you an example. If I echo just `$pilotid`, it will give me 5. Because it is on the profile page of the pilot, and his `pilotid` is 5. Now, all I'm trying to achieve is get the total of departures from a given airport, but assigned to a specific `pilotid` which we have just told the code to find.

Comment: @zzwyb89 Do you want the depatures of ALL pilots, or just the one that's currently accessing the CMS?

Comment: The one currently accessing CMS. The code is being sticked on a profile page, so it assigns the `pilotid` to pilot's profile. Can't explain this really well, but if you enter ID 4's profile, you'll get his departures if you catch what I'm saying.

Comment: @zzwyb89 Okay, this addendum should help you get what you want. Please remember, that the code is completely untested and may need some tweaking.

Comment: There's something wrong, and I can't really understand what it is. `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` http://pastebin.com/aW5pwd0q

Comment: @zzwyb89 That usually means, that the query has an error in it. There should be some sort of error message regarding what it is. You know, like `mysql_error`. In either case, `fav_deps` seems to come out as NULL or something else, that's not recognizable as an array. Please make sure, that $pilotid is actually an integer. Otherwise, the query is bound to fail, because SQL wouldn't know what ID to look for.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is this (note the curly brackets):

```
<?php echo $pilotid->{$departures->total}; ?>
```

Unless I'm misunderstanding the question...

Comment: I was thinking of something like this, but unfortunately it doesn't display anything either :(

Comment: This would work only if `$departures->total` contains a string, which is the same as an existing property of `$pilotid`.

Comment: `$departures->total` should be an integer, it calculates the total of departures from a pilotid. Anyway, might refer to the original question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15052778/ordering-by-specific-id-and-not-by-total-of-column/15052916#15052916

Comment: I assumed `$pilotid` was an object because you had said so, but now I see you're saying $pilotid is in integer...in which case it makes no sense to use the arrow notation (->) on it...

Comment: Alright, so what would be the most logic way to connect the two? I'm trying to calculate total amount of departures for a pilot, from a given airport. The airport is the `depicao` field in the table, the `pilotid` I take is obvious ;-)

Comment: It depends on how you want to display it...do you want to display a list of airports, with pilots listed under each, or a list of pilots, with airports listed under each pilot? I would just loop over your DB results and create stdClass objects to reflect the data structure that makes things easiest to display, rather than worrying about the constraints of the existing objects you're dealing with.